# Printing monochrome

Tags: printer, printing

How can I print in monochrome on my colour printer? Not grayscale, but only pure black-white printing?

Comment: Do you mean printing without dithering, halftoning or font-smoothing?

Comment: Can you specify operating system and application you are printing from as well?

Comment: Hi all, sorry for the late answer. The application in question is Autocad 2012. I was searching in printer options to find monochrome option, but instead i found it in Autocad.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, with modern printers, the idea of pure black and white printing is obsolete. Even where I have a black and white option on a printer (say a virtual PDF device, or my other printer), it *really* means greyscale.

Practically speaking your best option would be to tweak your source material to be black and white, then print that out